# How to use string column name inside dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider I have a table **TEMP** with two fields
UNIT ZONE
====   ====
Unit1   Zone1
Unit2   Zone2

I am trying to achieve the result of following simple query using dynamic query

```
select UNIT, ZONE from TEMP
```

My dynamic query is given below

```
declare @qry nvarchar(1000)
set @qry= 'declare @str varchar(100) = ''UNIT, ZONE''
select @str from TEMP '
execute sp_executesql @qry
```

But this query is selecting the string value (''UNIT, ZONE'') instead of the below rows

```
Unit1   Zone1
Unit2   Zone2
```

**In Short: How can I tell sql that @str specifies a column in table?**

I know this can be done by supplying parameter as follows, but unfortunately this is not what I want.

```
declare @qry varchar(1000)
declare @str varchar(100) = 'UNIT, ZONE'
set @qry ='select ' + @str + ' from TEMP'
execute sp_executesql @qry
```

Comment: Why on earth don't you want to do it the way that you already know works?  The whole reason for using DynamicSQL *(Dynamically writing a new query to execute with sp_executesql)* is that your variables can only ever be String Values and can Never be an object (database, schema, table, column, etc) reference...

Comment: Explain why you don't want to use the method you already know. It is not possible to give you an alternative if we don't know why the one you found is not applicable

Comment: @Paolo Thanks for your response. I know it looks weird but the field names also gets generated dynamically so I cannot declare it prior to calling 'execute'. While substituting the value can I make the query as _select foo from temp_ rather than _select 'foo' from temp_?

Comment: So column name get generated dynamically.  Put then in the @str.

Comment: @NidhinS describe your goal with details: here we're trying to provide a solution to an unknown problem. provide some context: with the limited statement in your post it is not clear what you want to achieve and without code we're not going to find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can try Dynamic SQL inside Dynamic SQL

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) = ''
set @query = '
declare @columns nvarchar(50) = ''Unit, Zone''
declare @innerQuery nvarchar(255) = '' select '' + @columns + '' from Table ''
exec(@innerQuery)
'
exec(@query)
```

but it will be real suicide ...

Comment: That's called inception :-)

Answer (score -1):

Look at it this way.

If you were to execute the query of the variable @qry yourself(i.e without sp_executesql):

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'UNIT, ZONE' 
select @str from TEMP
```

What would you get ? 
The answer is UNIT, ZONE ( repeated for the no. of rows in your table)

**So sp_executesql is performing its job correctly.**